# Why is my timeline not dissapearing and re appearing when I'm adding that function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I am making a timeline via [this guide](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-vertical-timeline-with-css-and-a-touch-of-javascript--cms-26528) and I am at the step of adding interactivity and then the hiding and revealing part. But my timeline wont dissapear and just stays there without moving, does anyone know how I could fix this problem and could actually make it firstly dissapear and then making it appear when you scroll down the page?

```css
.timeline ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: black;
  }
   
  .timeline ul li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: inherit;
  }

.timeline ul li div {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #F45B69;
}
   
.timeline ul li div::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) div {
    left: 45px;
}
   
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) div::before {
    left: -15px;
    border-width: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    border-color: transparent #F45B69 transparent transparent;
}
 
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div {
    left: -439px;
}
   
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div::before {
    right: -15px;
    border-width: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #F45B69;
}

.timeline ul li::after {
    background: #fff;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}
   
.timeline ul li.in-view::after {
    background: #F45B69;
}

  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) div {
    transform: translate3d(200px,0,0);
  }
   
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div {
    transform: translate3d(-200px,0,0);
  }

  .timeline ul li.in-view div {
    transform: none;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title>History of the Computer</title>
    <script src="history.j"></script>*/
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function isElementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }

  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline li");
 
// code for the isElementInViewport function
 
function callbackFunc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (isElementInViewport(items[i])) {
      items[i].classList.add("in-view");
    }
  }
}
 
window.addEventListener("load", callbackFunc);
window.addEventListener("scroll", callbackFunc);
    
    </script>
    


 <section class="timeline">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1801</time> In France, Joseph Marie Jacquard invents a loom that uses punched wooden cards to automatically weave fabric designs. Early computers would use similar punch cards.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1822</time> English mathematician Charles Babbage conceives of a steam-driven calculating machine that would be able to compute tables of numbers. The project, funded by the English government, is a failure. More than a century later, however, the world's first computer was actually built.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1890</time> Herman Hollerith designs a punch card system to calculate the 1880 census, accomplishing the task in just three years and saving the government $5 million. He establishes a company that would ultimately become IBM.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1936</time> Alan Turing presents the notion of a universal machine, later called the Turing machine, capable of computing anything that is computable. The central concept of the modern computer was based on his ideas.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1937</time> J.V. Atanasoff, a professor of physics and mathematics at Iowa State University, attempts to build the first computer without gears, cams, belts or shafts.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1939</time> Hewlett-Packard is founded by David Packard and Bill Hewlett in a Palo Alto, California, garage, according to the Computer History Museum. 
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1941</time>  Atanasoff and his graduate student, Clifford Berry, design a computer that can solve 29 equations simultaneously. This marks the first time a computer is able to store information on its main memory.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1943-1944</time>  Two University of Pennsylvania professors, John Mauchly and J. Presper Eckert, build the Electronic Numerical Integrator and Calculator (ENIAC). Considered the grandfather of digital computers, it fills a 20-foot by 40-foot room and has 18,000 vacuum tubes.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1946</time> Mauchly and Presper leave the University of Pennsylvania and receive funding from the Census Bureau to build the UNIVAC, the first commercial computer for business and government applications.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1947</time> William Shockley, John Bardeen and Walter Brattain of Bell Laboratories invent the transistor. They discovered how to make an electric switch with solid materials and no need for a vacuum. 
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1953</time> Grace Hopper develops the first computer language, which eventually becomes known as COBOL. Thomas Johnson Watson Jr., son of IBM CEO Thomas Johnson Watson Sr., conceives the IBM 701 EDPM to help the United Nations keep tabs on Korea during the war.
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first sight, it seems you're missing this piece of code:

```
.timeline ul li div {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```js
function isElementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }

  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline li");
 
// code for the isElementInViewport function
 
function callbackFunc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (isElementInViewport(items[i])) {
      items[i].classList.add("in-view");
    }
  }
}
 
window.addEventListener("load", callbackFunc);
window.addEventListener("scroll", callbackFunc);
```

```css
.timeline ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: black;
  }
   
  .timeline ul li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: inherit;
  }

.timeline ul li div {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #F45B69;
}
   
.timeline ul li div::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) div {
    left: 45px;
}
   
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) div::before {
    left: -15px;
    border-width: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    border-color: transparent #F45B69 transparent transparent;
}
 
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div {
    left: -439px;
}
   
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div::before {
    right: -15px;
    border-width: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #F45B69;
}

.timeline ul li::after {
    background: #fff;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}
   
.timeline ul li.in-view::after {
    background: #F45B69;
}

.timeline ul li div {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) div {
    transform: translate3d(200px,0,0);
  }
   
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div {
    transform: translate3d(-200px,0,0);
  }

  .timeline ul li.in-view div {
    transform: none;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<section class="timeline">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1801</time> In France, Joseph Marie Jacquard invents a loom that uses punched wooden cards to automatically weave fabric designs. Early computers would use similar punch cards.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1822</time> English mathematician Charles Babbage conceives of a steam-driven calculating machine that would be able to compute tables of numbers. The project, funded by the English government, is a failure. More than a century later, however, the world's first computer was actually built.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1890</time> Herman Hollerith designs a punch card system to calculate the 1880 census, accomplishing the task in just three years and saving the government $5 million. He establishes a company that would ultimately become IBM.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1936</time> Alan Turing presents the notion of a universal machine, later called the Turing machine, capable of computing anything that is computable. The central concept of the modern computer was based on his ideas.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1937</time> J.V. Atanasoff, a professor of physics and mathematics at Iowa State University, attempts to build the first computer without gears, cams, belts or shafts.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1939</time> Hewlett-Packard is founded by David Packard and Bill Hewlett in a Palo Alto, California, garage, according to the Computer History Museum. 
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1941</time>  Atanasoff and his graduate student, Clifford Berry, design a computer that can solve 29 equations simultaneously. This marks the first time a computer is able to store information on its main memory.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1943-1944</time>  Two University of Pennsylvania professors, John Mauchly and J. Presper Eckert, build the Electronic Numerical Integrator and Calculator (ENIAC). Considered the grandfather of digital computers, it fills a 20-foot by 40-foot room and has 18,000 vacuum tubes.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1946</time> Mauchly and Presper leave the University of Pennsylvania and receive funding from the Census Bureau to build the UNIVAC, the first commercial computer for business and government applications.
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1947</time> William Shockley, John Bardeen and Walter Brattain of Bell Laboratories invent the transistor. They discovered how to make an electric switch with solid materials and no need for a vacuum. 
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div>
     <time>1953</time> Grace Hopper develops the first computer language, which eventually becomes known as COBOL. Thomas Johnson Watson Jr., son of IBM CEO Thomas Johnson Watson Sr., conceives the IBM 701 EDPM to help the United Nations keep tabs on Korea during the war.
    </div>
   </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```